# Order of vanishing of an analytic function along its vanishing locus

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, differential-topology

Suppose $F: {\mathbb C}^n \to {\mathbb C}^k$ is a holomorphic/analytic function with vanishing locus $V_F = F^{-1}(0)$. Can one prove that there are positive real numbers $C>0$ and $\delta>0$ such that within a neighborhood of $V_F$ there holds
$$|F(x)| \geq C d(x, V_F)^\delta$$
(or at least inside a compact region)? Here $d$ is the distance function of the Euclidean (or any) metric.

Comment: Yes, this is the [Łojasiewicz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Łojasiewicz_inequality).